# ReactJS: Why isn't my div showing up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have basic index.html and index.js that don't do much except the minimum. My html file is this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
<script src="fb's react url"></script>
<script src="fb's reactDOM url"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="index.js"></script>
```

and my index.js file is this:

```
var Grid = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          grid: "Ola!"
        }
      },
      componentDidMount: function() {

      },
      render: function() {
        return ( < div > {
            Ola!
          } < /div >
        );
      }
  }
);

ReactDOM.render( < Grid / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

When I load my page (index.html) in Google Chrome, I just get a blank white screen. The console isn't outputting any errors. What could be going wrong? I am very new to React.js and most web technologies.

Comment: At first glance, `Ola!` inside `render` is being parsed by JavaScript (which is wrong) and those spaces around each tag might be screwing something up.

Comment: Then what should I put inside render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9fcyrbj3/

In JSX, everything that is inside curly braces will be evaluated as a Javascript, so it needs to be a valid JS expression.  `{ Ola! }` therefore would need to become `{ 'Ola!' }`.

However, you don't need curly braces here and you could simplify it like this:

```
render: function() {
    return (< div > Ola! < /div >);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `render` method as below. The `{}` in ReactJS evaluates the content inside as expression

```
render: function() {
    return ( 
      <div> Ola! </div>
    );
  }
```